# Error al compilar Qt de forma estática con driver de postgresql en Windows

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

tengo el problema de que al intentar compilar Qt de forma estática, me da un error cuando intento incluir los driver de Postgresql. Si no los incluyo, no tengo problemas. Si lo hago en linux incluyéndolos, tampoco. Solo es en Windows.

Al ejecutar el configure me da el siguiente error:

`ERROR: Feature 'sql-psql' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.psql' failed.`

Tengo instalado Postgresql, versión 9.6.

Si miro el archivo `config.log`, estas son las líneas relacionadas con psql:

> test config.qtbase_sqldrivers.libraries.odbc succeeded loaded result
>   for library config.qtbase_sqldrivers.libraries.psql Trying source 0
>   (type pkgConfig) of library psql ... pkg-config use disabled globally.
>   => source produced no result. Trying source 1 (type psqlConfig) of library psql ... pg_config not found.   => source produced no result.
>   Trying source 2 (type psqlEnv) of library psql ... None of
>   [liblibpq.dll.a liblibpq.a libpq.dll.a libpq.a libpq.lib] found in []
>   and global paths.   => source produced no result. Trying source 3
>   (type psqlEnv) of library psql ...   => source failed condition
>   '!config.win32'. test config.qtbase_sqldrivers.libraries.psql FAILED

Y esta es la forma en que llamo a `configure.bat`

`configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix C:\Qt\Static\5.13.0\ -opensource -confirm-license -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -no-openssl -sql-psql -I "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\include" -L "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\lib\libpq.lib" -opensource -confirm-license -skip webengine -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando compilar Qt con MinGW pero posiblemente has instalado una versión de PostgreSQL precompilado con MSVC++. Esto es una sospecha porque no hay ninguna prueba de esto en tu pregunta. Con bibliotecas estáticas, esto normalmente no funciona. En cambio, con DLLs hay mayor compatibilidad entre compiladores. Deberías usar el mismo compilador en los dos proyectos. Luego ninguno de los 4 métodos automáticos de detección de PgSQL ha funcionado. Probablemente te falta incluir el directorio bin de PgSQL en el PATH para la sesión de CMD en la que ejecutas configure.bat

Comment: Un mes después,,,,,muchas gracias por la respuesta. Ciertamente ese era el problema.